# How can I transmute a `MaybeUninit<T>` to a `T`?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I'd like to transmute a `MaybeUninit<T>` to a `T`.

```rust
use std::mem::transmute;
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

fn make_init<T: Sized>(mt: MaybeUninit<T>) -> T {
    unsafe { transmute(mt) }
}

fn main() {
    make_init(MaybeUninit::new(1));
}
```

However this program gives me:

```
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: On an aside: `make_init()` should be marked `unsafe` because it depends on `mt` actually having been initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the workaround when the compiler doesn't know that types have the same size is to use [`transmute_copy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute_copy.html), but in your case there is [`MaybeUninit::assume_init()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.assume_init-1) that does exactly what you want.